# Excel Avoiding nested if statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a datasheet in Excel with several columns to a row of data. Across these columns I have dates.
These dates show the time an item has passed a certain criteria. Is there a way (via formula) a way to have excel look at each column on a line and spit out only the lastest date.

Currently I am using this monster:

```
=IF(X3="",IF(W3="",IF(V3="",IF(U3="",IF(S3="",IF(R3="",IF(Q3="",IF(P3="",IF(O3="",IF(N3="","No Dates",N3),O3),P3),Q3),R3),S3),U3),V3),W3),X3)
```

It works fine, but I'm looking for something a little more elegant.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Is it true that the columns would always be filled in sequentially?  In particular, will a date go into column B before into column C?  Also, to be clear, you want the "rightmost" date, rather than the "latest" date?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't seem clear. I do in fact want the "Lastest" (or farthest into the future), not the right most. Also needs to always return a date value because sometimes there might be something other than dates written in the date fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the latest date, use

```
=MAX(N2:X2)
```

If you want the right most date, use this array formula

```
=INDEX(A2:X2,1,MAX((NOT(ISBLANK(N2:X2)))*(COLUMN(N2:X2))))
```

Enter array formulas with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.  Is finds the largest column that isn't blank and inserts that into INDEX.

Comment: Turns out I merely needed Max, thank you for the simple answer. Trying to get the fancy Index-Array formula to work, just so I understand it. Having difficulties. But thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most recent date in Row1:

```
=MAX(1:1)
```

If you want the date furthest to the right in Row1:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+100,1:1))
```

Comment: I started with MATCH too. MATCH won't work reliably unless the data is sorted, in which case MAX will return the right most.

Comment: @DickKusleika Unless you have a specific value to match within a specific range, I don't see anything working unreliably with `MATCH`.

Comment: Well, I can't get it to break. I thought the binary search started in the middle and would stop prematurely under certain circumstances with unsorted data. But I can't make it fail, so I must not understand it like I thought I did.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the row of dates and select the 'value field settings' option and summarize the value fields by max.  Excel will automatically generate the necessary formula to calculate the latest date.

Comment: Google it for your current version of Excel.  It changes depending on your year.

Comment: Sorry, in my test case, I used a table of data and that is option in pane.  If not table, use max, as pnuts answered.